# Strange animation with transition on transform matrix

Tags: css, transform, css-transitions

I'm getting a weird behaviour in my animation when I'm using transition on `transform:matrix()`. I'm only changing one parameter, but in the transition it looks like it's handling multiple parameters.

Hard to explain, so here's an example:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
  transform: matrix(1, -.5, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transition: transform .5s ease;
}
div:hover span {
  transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

[External jsbin link](http://jsbin.com/gotevalesa/1/)

As you can see, it's only supposed to animate the bottom right corner (the top left is animated too, but out of view), but it seems to be doing something strange in the upper left hand corner. Any ideas how to get around this? Is there some trick to transitioning between `transform:matrix`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `transform: skewY(-28deg);` rather than `transform: matrix(1,-.5,0,1,0,0);` and  `transform: skewY(0);` rather than `transform: matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0);`

Like I say [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30528819/matrix-scale-transition-not-working/30690873#30690873)

When animating or transitioning transforms, the transform function lists must be interpolated. Two transform functions with the same name and the same number of arguments are interpolated numerically without a former conversion. The calculated value will be of the same transform function type with the same number of arguments.

Special rules apply to rotate3d(), matrix(), matrix3d() and perspective(). The transform functions matrix(), matrix3d() and perspective() get converted into 4x4 matrices first and interpolated. If one of the matrices for interpolation is singular or non-invertible (iff its determinant is 0), the transformed element is not rendered and the used animation function must fall-back to a discrete animation according to the rules of the respective animation specification.

maybe at some point in the transition(you'll have to do the math) appears a singular matrix and the animation function must fall-back to a discrete animation

[Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/) is the full information

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to increase the `scaleX` and `scaleY` then decrease the `translateX`:

```
transform: matrix(1.2, 0, 0, 1.2, -30, 0);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/favuhokima/1/)**

Trick? I don't think so, but it behaves like using skew in a photo editor (e.g Photoshop).
If you skew an element and then skew it again to bring it back to its original state(by doing it slowly) you may see the same behaviour

Comment: Yeah, I started playing around with the scale as well, but as you can see, that creates another issue in the bottom left corner, where it will go up a bit, before going down again. Nitpicking, but I really want the whole thing to be as smooth as possible. I just want to understand why it's doing anything to the upper right corner. Because if I step through the animation "manually", there's at no point anything happening in the upper left corner...

Comment: Oh... you can try to change the origin to (0,0) or to center, it may help a bit.